# mysql - replace string with percentage sign

Tags: mysql, replace, special-characters, database-administration

In a particular column, I need to batch replace all instances of "http://%20" with "http://". The aim is to get rid of the %20 HTML entity which denotes an empty space.

I've tried

```
 update content set fulltext = replace(fulltext,'http://%20','http://');
```

but keep getting an error code #1064.

content is the table name and flutist is the column.

I guess something must be done about the percentage sign, since MySQL parses to as a wildcard.

MySQL 5.5.43 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: `fulltext` is a reserved word. Add backticks ``` around the field name or use a different field name

Comment: % is a special character. Did you try to escape it? Like this: replace(fulltext,'\%20','');

Comment: @Pekka웃 . . . You should add your comment as an answer, so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

`fulltext` is a [reserved word.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Add backticks

```
`fulltext`
```

around the field name or use a different field name.

Comment: The error is gone. Thanks. Now I just need to find a way to look for matches using wildcards. update kqju_content set `fulltext` = replace(`fulltext`,'%%20http%','http://'); is not doing the trick. Thought MySQL would parse the first % as an operational wildcard, but that's not the case.

Comment: @manchine not sure what you'd expect the first `%` to do? `REPLACE()` should replace the string anywhere, a wildcard shouldn't be necessary, no?

Comment: not quite; i still find instances of %20http:// after running the query. as if its syntax were not matching them.

Comment: `%` is not a special character in general. It is *only* treated as a wildcard when using `LIKE`.

Comment: Maybe the column contains some non-printable character like `\0` between `%20` and `http://`? That may explain why the REPLACE did not work in all occurances.